# Matlab - Reading CSV data

Tags: matlab, csv, input

I need to import data from a CSV file containing text and numbers, as shown below. csvread and other methods dont seem to be working, is there a way around this?

[image]

Comment: How much of the information do you need? Only the numbers? There is no way to store all that information in a single matrix in MATLAB. The closest you can get is [`table`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html). You can for instance not include `A1:A4` in such a table.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [`readtable`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html):

```
T = readtable('csv_file.csv',...
    'Range','CA4:F11',...
    'ReadVariableNames',true)
```

I'm not sure if it will be able to handle `% TYPE` in A4, but you might have to delete that cell for this to work.

Note: You have to save this as a .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm, .xltx, or .xltm-file for this to work. It's easy to import a [csv file into excel](https://superuser.com/a/407085/231959) and save it as an `xlsx`-file, so that shouldn't be a problem if you have MS Office.

It's of course possible to do this using the csv-file directly, but that's a bit more messy.